# Chrome is not showing saved passwords

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, manjaro

Yesterday, I installed Manjaro OS on my PC, for the first day everything was fine, but today when I opened chrome, my account was **PAUSED**, so I sign in again, but then I noticed something unusual, I was logged out of every website on my browser, I tried to log-in into them but autofill was not suggesting any password, so I checked in setting and **there was no password**, I immediately checked in my phone(my phone and pc are synced), there everything was fine, then I checked https://passwords.google.com/ and there too everything was fine.

I have checked everything, my devices are synced, everything is fine with bookmarks, history, extensions, addresses etc., the problem is only with passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to be using manjaro as well and I installed cutefish desktop, I rebooted into cutefish and opened chrome then I noticed that all my passwords were gone. What fixed my problem was renaming chrome settings folder which is a hidden folder located at /home/XXX/.config/google-chrome, once I renamed it and opened chrome I needed to sign in with my email, and voila, all my info was back. My guess is something got corrupted in that folder, I hope this helps